# Loop in the svg.js

Tags: loops, animation, svg.js

```
rect
    .animate(1000,"<>",0).dmove(50,0)
    .animate(1000,"<>",0).dmove(-10,0)
    .animate(1000,"<>",0).dmove(20,0)
    .animate(1000,"<>",0).dmove(-60,0).loop(true, true);
```

Why (and should it?) does the loop not repeat the entire animation? He skips 2 and the 3 step.

Demonstration: https://codepen.io/Andreslav/pen/BxGygp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar issue was solved [here](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/498). The solution can be adapted for your problem:

```
let w = 100,
        h = 100,
        t = 1000,
        draw = SVG('svg').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,w,h);


function animation() {
    draw.rect(10,10)
        .animate(t,">",0).dx(w/2).width(20).height(10)
        .animate(t,">",0).dy(h/2).width(15).height(15)
        .animate(t,">",0).dx(-w/2).width(10).height(15)
        .animate(t,">",0).dy(-h/2).width(10).height(10).after(animation)

}
    animation()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `loop` only works on the last action.

You can try a different approach to accomplish the same thing by using a path.

E.g: (you'll need to adjust to replicate the same points)

```
let width = 1000,
height = 100,
draw = SVG('svg').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,width,height);

// use path to replicate movement
const path = draw.path("M200 0 H 250 H 100 H 120 H 80")
const length = path.length()

path.fill('none').stroke({width:1, color: '#ccc'})

const rect = draw.rect(100, 100)
rect.animate(5000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length)
    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
}).loop(true, true)
```

(from [tutorials](http://svgjs.com/tutorials/))

Comment: Brilliantly! Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: But still it does not solve the problem. For example, with color or transformation, such a trick will not work. I'll have to use recursion.